Project Dependencies GraphQL internal server error possibly due to Alpine packager
Recently, while trying query using GraphQL for dependencies, I was met with an internal server error when attempting to include packager value into the query.
Query:
{
    project(fullPath: "<your_project_path>") {
        dependencies (after:"MTUwMA") {
            edges {
                node {
                    id
                    name
                    version
                    location {
                        path
                    }
                    packager
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Response
{
    "errors": [
        {
        "message": "Internal server error"
        }
    ]
} 

Removing the packager value from the query seems to resolve the issue. It appears that Alpine as a packager is triggering the internal server error. We didn't face any errors before page "MTUwMA", where npm serves as the packager for all dependencies. However, after page "MTUwMA", where Alpine dependencies, specifically alpine:3.18.6 (apk), are introduced as the packager, it returns a status 500 error.

If you guys encounter a similar issue with the packager value in the dependencies field, please advise on how to resolve this issue. 
Thanks in advance!
